# Show only email that arrived within the last X minutes

Tags: gmail

Confirmation emails are sometimes required for signing up for a webpage or sometimes just for logging into a page with 2FA.
I don't want to see any other emails, rather than the specific email, that I opened Gmail for, because they could distract me from what I actually wanted to do in the first place.

So I want Gmail to only show me emails, that arrived within a couple of minutes from 'right now'to minimize potential distractions. How can I do this within Gmail?

I was thinking, I could use a link to search my inbox with a specific filter, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you can specify the number of hours:

To only show a portion of your email use multiple unboxes.

- To turn it on go to gear->settings.
- then to advanced
- select multiple inboxes.

that should give you a new settings tab.

You can then specify one of the new inboxes to show items newer than 1 hour.
newer_than:1h

if you tell it to put the new inbox above the main inbox then the new items will be in a separate inbox above the rest.

Comment: I found I could also 'section' this inbox off and open it and only it with its URL, without having to see the other, cluttered inboxes. Problem is though, that when I archive an Email it still shows up in that 'Inbox', which is not how I'm used to inboxes behaving. Any idea, how I can make them vanish from it, after archiving?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Gmail's search operators based on time only go down to the day, not any smaller.

You can, however, search for things that are newer than a day and that will get you most of the way there.

```
newer_than:1d
```

You can, of course, add whatever other search terms you need.

You can't do this as a filter. Filters kick off when the message comes in, and a filter like that will match everything. You can, however, create a link with that operator embedded in the URL.

Comment: This isn't exactly correct as you can query for hours with `h`